# trying to use & and operation in scala

Tags: scala

case class takes 3 parameters id, applied by and internal name. Trying to make the result lenght return 3. internal name was a newly added field/parameter so that is why it is returning 0 instead of 3.

I was think to use

```
result.topics.find(_.topicId == "urn:emmet:1234567").get.appliedBy should be ("human") &
  result.topics.find(_.topicId == "urn:emmet:2345678").get.internalName should be ("")
```

it's giving me syntax error, please advice thanks in advance

```
 it should "dedup topics by id, keeping those applied by human if possible" in {
val doc = Document.empty.copy(
  topics = Array(
    Topic("urn:emmet:1234567", appliedBy = "machine" , internalName = ""),
    Topic("urn:emmet:2345678", appliedBy = "human", internalName = ""),
    Topic("urn:emmet:1234567", appliedBy = "human", internalName = ""),
    Topic("urn:emmet:2345678", appliedBy = "machine", internalName = ""),
    Topic("urn:emmet:3456789", appliedBy = "machine", internalName = ""),
    Topic("urn:emmet:3456789", appliedBy = "machine", internalName = "")
  )
)

val result = DocumentTransform.dedupSubRecords(doc)

result.topics.length should be (3)
result.topics.find(_.topicId == "urn:emmet:1234567").get.appliedBy should be ("human")
result.topics.find(_.topicId == "urn:emmet:2345678").get.appliedBy should be ("human")
result.topics.find(_.topicId == "urn:emmet:3456789").get.appliedBy should be ("machine")
```

}

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with `&`? Can you provide a minimal working example? It looks like you're using scalatest, can you tag it as such so those that can help you are more likely to see it?

Comment: that is correct it is unit test. & is for exactly that another additional condition along with `should be "human"`.... trying to include another should be this time with internalName field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple test statements are already an 'and', because if any one of them fails the whole test fails.

```
val e1234567 = result.topics.find(_.topicId == "urn:emmet:1234567").get
e1234567.appliedBy shouldEqual "human"
e1234567.internalName shouldEqual ""
```

Comment: Using `.get` is unsafe: `.find(..).exists { x => x.appliedBy == "human" && x.internalName == "" } shouldEqual true` (or `must beSome.like` using Specs2)